# SELECT With MySQL Stored Function in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I got a stored function named `getItemQty()` in my database. When I run this code from localhost its loading the data's.

```
     SELECT ItemId, CatalogNUmber, Cost, getItemQty(ItemId), 
     Minimum, Maximum, TypeId, SupplierId FROM items;

     Showing rows 0 - 24 (4387 total, Query took 2.4682 seconds.)
```

Its working fine in localhost but when I apply it to my DataGridView. Its loading takes forever and the `timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed` show.

Heres my code to populate **DataGridView**.

```
            Dim command As New MySqlCommand()
            Dim cmdstring As String
            Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            cmdstring = "SELECT ItemId, CatalogNUmber, Cost, getItemQty(ItemId), Minimum, Maximum, TypeId, SupplierId FROM items;"
            With command
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandText = cmdstring
                .CommandTimeout = 60
            End With
            conn.Open()
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(dt)
            dgvStocks.DataSource = dt
            command.Dispose()
            adapter.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
```

How Can I load the data in **DataGridView** like in localhost? Also if its ok what causing this loading?

Comment: best way to spot error yourself is to add a breakpoint to view datatable

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: using visual studio ?

Comment: `Dim command As New MySqlCommand()` break always (currently 1)

Comment: place break point at : dgvStocks.DataSource = dt

Comment: and check values in dt

Comment: `adapter.fill(dt)` break always (currently 1)

Comment: What do you mean by `Its working fine in localhost but when I apply it to my DataGridView. Its loading takes forever` ... are you changing servers?

Comment: no I'm not I think the problem is the procedure is working on vb,net but  stored function is not recognized? I'm not sure but I tried another stored procedure without stored function then its showing the data