# SELECT WITH CALL PROCEDURE MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I got a Stored Procedure names `getStocks` that have a parameter. The code below is a example how I want to do with the query. Is it possible with the **SELECT QUERY** we can call a procedure?

> **PS I didn't use Function cuz I'm getting loading problem when I apply it in populating DataGridview in my VB.Net**

```
BEGIN

SELECT ItemId, CatalogNumber, call getStocks(ItemId) AS quantity, 
Cost, Minimum, Maximum, TypeId, SupplierId FROM items;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant do this. `CALL` is its own statement that you cant mix with `SELECT` in any way. If you cant use a UDF, you have to preform the integration manually.

It makes sense that a `CALL` cant be used like this when you consider that a `CALL` can optionally output a resultset. It might return a resultset, it might now. It might have one cell, one row, one column, or many rows/columns. The columns are not known at call time so the optimizer couldn't validate any `JOIN`s to it if you put a call in the `FROM` and the because it can produce more than one cell (or nothing), you cant reliably put it in the `SELECT`. Additionally, stored procedures can have output variables, which also doesnt make sence in the context of a `SELECT` statement.

In other words, because the output of procedures is probably incompatible with any part of a `SELECT` query, the makers of mysql globally prevent their mixing.

Comment: Thanks for the info sir :) see my other question thats why I tried this call procedure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631426/select-with-mysql-stored-function-in-vb-net?noredirect=1#comment64659782_38631426

Comment: sorry, not a vb guy. if you had the error, then I could help ;)

Comment: I dont know why in localhost it took 2.xxx seconds to generate the data when applying it in vb it just loading until the timeout pop-out

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a User-Defined Function (UDF) : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html . Unlike stored procedures, UDF's may be called inline in a query.

Comment: I cant use function see my **PS**

Comment: What kind of loading problem are you getting? Are you getting an error message? Are you getting the wrong data? A UDF is the standard way to solve this kind of problem - you just might have a bug in your function. Please post it.

Comment: Here is my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631426/select-with-mysql-stored-function-in-vb-net?noredirect=1#comment64659782_38631426